# How to use new Android Architecture without using Lambda Expressions?

Tags: android, java-8, retrofit, dagger-2

I have followed [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html) tutorial, written directly by google.

The problem, that I currently have, is the line `userDao.save(response.body());` inside the `UserRepository` class.

```
 private void refreshUser(final String userId) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            // running in a background thread
            // check if user was fetched recently
            boolean userExists = userDao.hasUser(FRESH_TIMEOUT);
            if (!userExists) {
                // refresh the data
                Response response = webservice.getUser(userId).execute();
                // TODO check for error etc.
                // Update the database.The LiveData will automatically refresh so
                // we don't need to do anything else here besides updating the database
                userDao.save(response.body());
            }
        });
    }
```

When I try to do that in my Android Studio Version, I get a message which says that Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level.

[image]

I am aware of the fact that I can upgrade my Android Studio to support Java 8 like [that](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html), BUT- is there an other way to do so? I don't want to upgrade to Java 8 just to use Lambda Expressions.

Comment: Why would anyone *not* want to upgrade to Java 8?  All previous versions have been End Of Life for years now!

Comment: @JoeC That is not an exception that is thrown, it is a message from my ide, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JoeC because java 8 in android is still in beta, and using beta makes me kind of shaky

Comment: At the end of the day, a lambda is nothing more than an anonymous class.

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code as they are not searchable. Please [edit] your post to include the real code so it can help future users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use Java 8 (which you should reconsider), you can manually replace:

```
executor.execute(() -> {
    // task...
});
```

with:

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // task...
    }
});
```

Comment: How could I have been so blind?! I didn't see that my Runnable was the lambda class- actually you opened my eyes and helped me out! Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem. u can use a lambda in place of any anonymous inner class, especially click listeners: `button.setOnClickListener(v -> {  // code });`

Comment: Yeah, i was aware of that- but the fact that android doesn't support java 8 (with a release candidate) makes me skipping the lambas.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to use lambda, this is a two-option answer based on your AS version

## 2.3.3 and lower

First you need to enable jack and use Java 8. Note that jack is officially deprecated, but for AS 2.3.3 and lower it's the only option for getting Java 8 (really buggy option though. Lambda can be used in Java 7 (or lower) using a library, described at the end of this post):

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

## 3.0 (beta when writing this) and above

AS 3.0 supports java 8 without needing to activate Jack. So all you need is:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

---

Assuming you have Java 8 installed, you can now use lambda.

The other workaround (if you can't get Java 8 to compile or don't want to deal with jack or some completely other reason) is as [chornge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551987/6296561) said in his answer to not use lambda or Java 8 and just use the anonymous inner class system.

## Alternative

On a side-note, you wrote in your post that you don't want to use Java 8, but use lambda. You can (in theory, haven't tested this myself) use [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). It's a library that adds lambda support for Java <= 7

Comment: Jack is deprecated, while Retrolambda works perfectly fine.

Comment: I know jack is deprecated, it is still the only option to get Java 8 on AS <= 2.3.3. AS >= 3.0 allows Java 8 without jack. On lower versions of AS you still have to use jack even though it's deprecated (I have tried using Java 8 without jack using AS 2.3.3, but it shows that jack still is required). It is only in 3.0 jack became deprecated

Comment: Retrolambda also gives you lambda support. And it doesn't break things in the process. So I recommend against applying jack. It is officially deprecated. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you still miss the point. My answer covers the possible solutions, first the official ones and then libraries. (if you downvoted me over showing jack as a solution, that is was a waste of 1 rep for you). Whether someone decides to use jack or not is up to the given person. Jack is still a perfectly **valid** way of getting Java 8 when using AS 2.3.3 and lower, even if it is a bad one (compile time went up extreme amounts after adding it for me, but it is still a possible option that can work for some).

Comment: If you add the notice that Jack is officially deprecated to the answer then I'll undo the downvote though :p But Jack breaks things, for example Realm wouldn't compile with it.

Comment: There you go, notice added. It's deprecated, only way to get java 8 in AS 2.3.3 and lower, lambda can be used with a library as described at the end of the post

Answer (score 2):

`executor` is an instance of `Executor`. [`execute()` takes a `Runnable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)). So, replace the lambda expression with a `Runnable`.